# AndroidTV: UsageStatsManager not returning details for apps results after Reboot

Tags: android, android-tv, usagestatsmanager

I am working on a Android TV app (system app) where i am trying to use *UsageStatsManager* to get recently used app list.
By following approach ,

```
UsageStatsManager usm = getUsageStatsManager(context);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1)
final List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY, startTime, endTime);
```

**Above approach gives right usage data, but after a device reboot it wont give previously used app usage data**, until that app has been opened again after reboot .

But same code works fine (after reboot) in an android Phone .

I also tried this [sample App](https://github.com/quiro91/UsageStatsManager-Sample/) from Github in Android TV which also fails to give details after reboot in Android TV (but works in Mobile , both OS version 8) .

Any reason why it's failing to get App usage data for Android TV ?

TIA

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Android Tv .
I have checked in a rooted android tv box,  in path “/data/system/usagestats/0/"  
Before reboot , I can see last used time in Daily usage stats record.
But after a power cycle in same folder I don’t see the data of previously used app any more. Even I checked in weekly, monthly and yearly data but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nainal here is a workaround.

As we had experienced that after a device power cycle , Android Tv box won’t return the usage stats of installed application.  Here is a workaround I followed .

- We fetch the details of installed application then store only last used time in a Hash map.
- And we used a custom comparator to compare via last time used and sort our Installed application details list (ResolveInfo) ,  for recently used app list.
- Now to overcome the situation of device power cycle scenario, We are maintaining a  Hash map locally in app  . Where we will store the installed App’s Last used time  as Long millis (epoch) .  lastTimeUsedMap = new HashMap(); 
  And we update the map every time we get a new data from UsageStatsManager.
- We simplify the map object and store as string in shared preference.
- And after reboot first we will find in usage stats if installed package is having a time stamp or not . If not we will get the time from stored MAP .

Here is the code :

```
private void SortByRecentlyUsed(final List<ResolveInfo> info, final Context context){

    /*load LastTimeUsedMap from pref*/
    lastTimeUsedMap = loadLastTimeUsedMap(context);

    UsageStatsManager usm = getUsageStatsManager(context);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    final List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST, startTime, endTime);

    /*Update AppRecentTimeUsedMap with latest data from UsageStatsManager*/
    updateAppRecentTimeUsedMap(usageStatsList,info);

    class RecentUseComparator implements Comparator<ResolveInfo> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ResolveInfo lhs, ResolveInfo rhs) {
            String lhsPackageName=lhs.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            String rhsPackageName=rhs.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            long lhsUsedTime = getLastUsedTime(lhsPackageName);
            long rhsUsedTime = getLastUsedTime(rhsPackageName);
            return (lhsUsedTime > rhsUsedTime) ? -1 : (lhsUsedTime == rhsUsedTime) ? 0 : 1;
        }

        private long getLastUsedTime(String packageDetails) {
            long appRecentUsedtime = -1;
            if (appRecentTimeUsedMap.containsKey(packageDetails)) {
                appRecentUsedtime = appRecentTimeUsedMap.get(packageDetails);
                }
            return appRecentUsedtime;
        }
    }
    RecentUseComparator mRecentComp = new RecentUseComparator();
    Collections.sort(info, mRecentComp);
    /*Save the updated  LastTimeUsedMap in pref*/
    saveLastTimeUsedMap(lastTimeUsedMap, context);

}

private void updateAppRecentTimeUsedMap(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList,List<ResolveInfo> info){

    String packageName=null;
    if (usageStatsList != null) {
        for (ResolveInfo Rinfo : info) {
            packageName = Rinfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            boolean added = false;
            for (UsageStats usageStats : usageStatsList) {
                if (packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(usageStats.getPackageName())) {
                    appRecentTimeUsedMap.put(usageStats.getPackageName(), usageStats.getLastTimeUsed());
                    updateLastTimeUsedMap(usageStats.getPackageName(), usageStats.getLastTimeUsed());
                    added=true;
                }
            }
            if (!added && lastTimeUsedMap.containsKey(packageName)) {
                appRecentTimeUsedMap.put(packageName, lastTimeUsedMap.get(packageName));
            }
        }

    }

}

private void updateLastTimeUsedMap(String packageName,Long timeStamp){
    lastTimeUsedMap.put(packageName, timeStamp);
}

/**
 * Return Map containing Package name and recent used time from preference
 *
 * @param context
 * @return Map<String,Long>
 */
private Map<String,Long> loadLastTimeUsedMap(Context context){
    Map<String,Long> outputMap = new HashMap<String,Long>();
    SharedPreferences pSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(LAST_TIME_USED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    try{
        if (pSharedPref != null){
            String jsonString = pSharedPref.getString(LAST_TIME_USED_MAP, (new JSONObject()).toString());
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            Iterator<String> keysItr = jsonObject.keys();
            while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
                String key = keysItr.next();
                Long value = jsonObject.getLong(key);
                outputMap.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputMap;
}
/**
 * Save the updated map containing Package name and recent used time in preference
 *
 * @param inputMap
 * @param context
 */
private void saveLastTimeUsedMap(Map<String,Long> inputMap, Context context){
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(LAST_TIME_USED_PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences != null){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(inputMap);
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove(LAST_TIME_USED_MAP).commit();
        editor.putString(LAST_TIME_USED_MAP, jsonString);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```